# Exit Sub for a repeater in ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want exit rpt.ItemDataBound function  at the 4 fourth iteration  but when i've done :

```
 Protected Sub rptCol_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCol.ItemDataBound
        If Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem AndAlso Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then Exit Sub
        If e.Item.ItemIndex = 4 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

..

it didn't work , he just skip this iteration.

any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: The `ItemDataBound` method is called *after* the item has been generated for any extra logic.  There is no effect in skipping the event.  Are you trying to leave those rows out entirely?

Comment: yes, exactly. i tried also return instead of exist sub but it didn't work

Comment: try "If e.Item.ItemIndex >= 4 Then"  But this will just prevent databinding of these items (not templating, and itemcreated handling)

Comment: @user1187282 Are you trying to implement pagination in Repeater Control? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Marcus said, the iteration will continue because it is called for every row.

Try a different approach. Alter your datasource *before* binding to the repeater. Something like this:

```
//I am assuming your datasource is a List, but this works for a datatable, etc
List<[YOUR CLASS]> datasource = MethodThatGetsYourSource();
rptCol.DataSource = datasource.Take(4);
rptCol.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ForceStopAfterFirstBind(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemIndex > 3 Then
        e.Item.Controls.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

call it this way:

```
ForceStopAfterFirstBind(sender, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try the itemCreadedOnDatabound event

Comment: i've tried it but it didn't work here is what i did.                  Protected Sub rptCol_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCol.ItemCreated
        If e.Item.ItemIndex = 3 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The iteration will continue because the event handler will continue be called for every row. If want to skip the logic after certain row, you could do something like:

```
Protected Sub rptCol_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCol.ItemDataBound
    If Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem AndAlso Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then Exit Sub
    If e.Item.ItemIndex > 3 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
 .....
End Sub
```

Comment: i want to  exit the function not just skip the item,  is it possible <